# Why does webview NOT always work?

Tags: android, webview

I have internet permission in my manifest, I am trying to search for "facebook" on the searchbar of my webview, but the problem is, for the 50% searches, It does not load the search request! this is so weird and frustrating. I implemented everything correctly and checked everything 3 times, but no luck. every time I search for the same on other browsers, It always works. but when I search on my webview, It sometimes loads the page, and most of the times, progress bar shows loading, and disappears as if the page has actually loaded, but it is still white. Why is this happening???

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText searchEditText;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private WebView webView;
private String SearchString = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    // use keyboard go button to search
    searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    searchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            CustomSearch();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "page error. please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
}

private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}

 public void CustomSearch() {
    searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    String url = searchEditText.getText().toString();
    url = SearchString + url.replace(" ", "+");// replace_spaces_with_a_"+"_sign(prefix)
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: have you inspected your logs?

Also what are you trying to do? are you trying to have a browser inside your app? if that is the case, use chrome custom tabs instead. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs but note that the minimum api for that is 16

Comment: a minimum api 16, and chrome browser installed?

Comment: api 16 yes. If chrome is not installed, I believe it will use the default browser of the phone... btw, what are you trying to do? just redirecting the user to a url or you really want to have a browser where the user can type? because if you just want to redirect the user to browser, you don't need webview or chrome custom tabs.

Comment: I want my own browser and a floating action button on bottom

Answer (score 0):

Did you try encoding your search text, as per my understanding you need to encode the search string.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: and it searches sometimes, but does not search most of the time

Comment: You should try to use url encode and try that if that works.